# casting a Stack as a double

Tags: java, stack, double

Okay, so here's the line of code I'm having trouble with:

```
double endNumber = (double)numbers.pop();
return endNumber;
```

My problem is that I need the number that pops off the stack as a double, but I keep getting the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: The answers below are right, but I would highly suggest looking into generics. Make your stack parameterized to the type of references it stores -- in this case, `String`, but it could be anything. That way, you don't have to put the cast in (the compiler does it for you), and you get type checking that would make it clear that `numbers.pop()` returns a `String` which you must then parse.

Comment: The thing you pop is the last thing you pushed. If the last thing you pushed was a string, then the thing popped will be a string, and you can't cast strings to doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the item that you popped off the stack into a double:

```
double endNumber = Double.parseDouble(numbers.pop());
return endNumber;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `pop()` method returns `String`, and, you have to parse it to `double`

```
double endNumber = Double.parseDouble(numbers.pop());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return Double.parseDouble(numbers.pop());
```

Answer (score 1):

You ll have to use `Double.parseDouble(argument)`

```
double endNumber = Double.parseDouble(numbers.pop());
```

or you can directly return without using any `double` variable.